# Windows 64bit programs incorrectly installed

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

Okay, this question has ran through my brain for a while but I can't find anything online for it.

I know that on a 64bit version of Windows the 64bit programs are stored in "Program Files", and 32bit programs are stored in "Program Files(x86)" to organize the different programs. However (not really a big issue, more just curious) I have noticed that even when I download a 64bit version of a program (like iTunes) they still (by default) install to "Program Files (x86)"

My question is ... ***Why?***

Is it because the "64bit" programs being stored in 'program files (x86)' are not true 64bit programs ... like dll files still using 32bit architecture?

If the two different folders are not even being put to "full" use then whats the point?

I am just trying to get a clear picture.

Comment: iTunes does not exist as a 64-bit application, I am not aware of a 64-bit version of notepad++

Comment: Ah yes, Poor example on my part about notepad++ I will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell:

**The install folder doesn't make a difference**

- 32-bit programs can be installed into, and work just fine, in either `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)`
- 64-bit programs can be installed into, and work just fine, in either `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)`

**64-bit isn't the same as 64-bit compatible**

Some software that is pure 32-bit is advertised as being 64-bit *compatible*. The way it's advertised can be misleading – you might be lead to believe that the software is actually 64-bit when really it's 32-bit but 64-bit compatible.

**Software can comprise of both 32-bit and 64-bit components**

This is extremely common. A lot of software is made up of 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs/EXEs. The vendor gets to decide whether the software will install to `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)`.

**What's the point?**

Go figure. I'm sure there was a reason, but so far as I'm concerned the delineation is pointless. I found some info, makes for interesting reading...

http://www.howtogeek.com/129178/why-does-64-bit-windows-need-a-separate-program-files-x86-folder/

Comment: That makes sense. Its just my OCD I guess its all too mixed up. lol

Answer (score 0):

misha256 has done a good job of explaining the situation but, you've specifically asked **why** they decided to make two program files directories. The reason for that is because this design makes distribution of software which targets both systems easier. Since there are two directories for program files an application may install 32bit binaries and 64 bit binaries at the same time without using separate file names. There are MANY ways this could've been done but the one you see is the way they chose to go. A big part of the reason they did is because this layout is the best for backwards compatibility. Old programs which use [%PROGRAMFILES%](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9608782/932549) will still work exactly the same aside from the small difference of " (x86)" in the path (but that won't matter as long as the program uses paths relative to %PROGRAMFILES% [as it should've always been doing]). WOW64 is able to simply modify the value of %PROGRAMFILES% for 32-bit apps and they will only see 32bit binaries under %PROGRAMFILES% this way.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made the why have a full sentence. I already understand why there are the two separate folders. misha256 got what I meant.